# Facebook photo API

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am having serious issues trying to use the Javascript API for facebook. I currently have a somewhat functioning facebook login, and I want to be able to get all of the photos from the current user, and have them displayed in a strip. I am pretty new to Javascript, so I was wondering if somebody has gotten this to work, or what would be the best way to accomplish this, preferably without using the deprecated FQL.

Comment: I believe it was because I added "thanks" to the bottom.

Comment: From my perspective (I didn't downvote), the question is not a question.  Note the lack of question mark.

Comment: Not only the lack of question mark.

Comment: To avoid down votes (I didn't btw) try including what you have tried, what didn't work and any code samples related to the above. Having shown an attempt to resolve the problem yourself will reduce the chances of being down voted

Comment: I would like to think the downvote was exactly as @jonP said... you show no attempt whatsoever at solving your problem (*or that is the appearance when you show none of the attempts in your question*)

Comment: Sorry guys, it was my first question. Thanks for the suggestions, and I apologize for the lack of a question mark. I will better construct my questions in the future. I tried using the FB.api(me/photos) or something of the sort, but I just couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 5000 item limit for FQL queries, but that should cover a good amount of the photos you are looking to get:

```
var query = 'SELECT src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN(SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner = me())';

FB.api('fql', {'q': query}, function(res) {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

Then you can loop through that result set and add the photos to the document (using jQuery in this sample loop:

```
var body = $(document.body);

for(var i in res.data) {
   body.append('<img src="' + res.data[i].src_big + '" />');
}
```

Comment: Alright, I read that on the FB site I think. But it seems to be in widespread use. Thank you very much zachilla.

Comment: They did deprecate a ton of old APIs, however they recently made it easier to make FQL queries using the Graph API, and said they were not deprecating FQL. Good news, for sure!

Comment: Sorry I never confirmed the answer. Theres your rep :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with these two resources.  The JavaScript SDK includes all the features of the Graph API of which photo information is a core piece.

- [Facebook Photo API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/)
- [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/)

Comment: Thanks, i'll have a look into these. I tried using the Javascript SDK, but I was stumped as to how I would go about retrieving the photos.